# Maximize $\frac{\sin(2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}$

Tags: trigonometry

I want to maximize $\frac{\sin(2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}$. I converted both $\sin$ and $\cos$ to $\tan$ and got answer $$\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}$$ achieved for example at $x=\operatorname{arccot}(\sqrt2)$. Please give some another approach without using the above conversion formula.

Comment: Using half-angle substitution: Let $t=\tan\left(\frac x2\right)$ then by AM-GM or calculus $$\frac{\sin(2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}=\frac{2 t}{8 t^2+1}\le\frac{t}{t\sqrt 8}=\frac1{2\sqrt 2}$$ with equality iff $t=\frac1{2\sqrt 2}$.

Comment: Unable to understand your substitution

Comment: Please see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution

Comment: Son't need $\tan (x/2)$, you could put $t= \tan x$

Comment: @Aqua True but I was lazy

Comment: Why don't you put it as an answer? @MaximilianJanisch

Comment: @Maximilian Janisch thanks

Comment: What do you call "the above conversion formula" ?? In fact, you show us nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another Approach :

Since a point $(\cos (2t), \sin (2t))$ is on a circle $x^2 + y^2 = 1$,

we can understand $\frac{\sin (2x)}{3-\cos(2x)} = \frac{0-\sin (2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}$ by slope of tangent line between a point $(3, 0)$ and a circle $x^2+y^2=1$.

After calculations, we can get :$$\max\left\{\frac{\sin (2x)}{3-\cos(2x)} \right\} = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}} \\
\min\left\{\frac{\sin (2x)}{3-\cos(2x)} \right\} = -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $$k=\frac{\sin 2x}{3-\cos 2x}$$

$\displaystyle 3k-k\cos(2x)=\sin 2x\Longrightarrow 3k=\sin 2x+k\cos 2x$

Using $$|a\sin t+b\cos t|\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\;\forall \;t\;\in \mathbb{R}$$

getting $|\sin 2x+k\cos 2x|\leq \sqrt{1+k^2}$

$$|3k|\leq \sqrt{1+k^2}$$

$$9k^2\leq 1+k^2\Longrightarrow 8k^2\leq 1$$

$$\bigg(k-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\bigg(k+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\bigg)\Longrightarrow -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\leq k\leq \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x)=\frac{\sin 2x}{3-\cos 2x}.$ Then show that

$f'(x) =0 \iff \cos(2x)=1/3.$

If $\cos(2x)=1/3$, then $ \sin (2x)= \pm \frac{\sqrt{8}}{3}.$

This shows:

$$ \max f( \mathbb R)= \frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

and

$$ \min f( \mathbb R)= -\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}.$$

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maximizing $\frac{\sin(2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}$ you can **minimize** $\frac{3-\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)}$ on its positive range, hence, where $\sin 2x= 2\sin x \cos x >0$:

$$\frac{3-\cos(2x)}{\sin(2x)} \stackrel{\cos 2x= 1-2\sin^2 x}{=} \frac{2+2\sin^2x}{2\sin x \cos x}=\frac{1+\sin^2x}{\sin x \cos x}$$
$$= \frac{2\sin^2x+\cos^2 x}{\sin x \cos x} \stackrel{a^2+b^2 \geq 2ab}{\geq} \frac{2\sqrt{2}\sin x\cos x}{\sin x \cos x}=2\sqrt{2}$$

Hence, the maximum of $\frac{\sin(2x)}{3-\cos(2x)}$ is the reciprocal $\boxed{\frac 1{2\sqrt{2}}}$.

Answer (score -1):

Hint

Use https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution#The_substitution
to replace $\sin2x,\cos2x$ with $$\dfrac{2t}{1+t^2},\dfrac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$ respectively where $t=\tan x$ to  find

$\dfrac{\sin2x}{3-\cos2x}=\dfrac{2t}{3(1+t^2)-(1-t^2)}=y$(say)

Method$\#1:$

Rearrange the relationship to form a quadratic equation in $t$

As $t$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Method$\#2:$

$$y=\dfrac t{1+2t^2}$$

If $t\ge0,$ $$\dfrac{1+2t^2}t\ge2\sqrt{\dfrac1t\cdot2t}=?$$

If $t<0,$ set $t=-u$